# Win7 add DNS suffixes after primary

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I want to use the primary DNS suffix provided by the router on the given LAN I'm connecting to. And after that I want a small set of suffixes that never change. For example:

Office DNS suffix: `office.example.com.`

Home DNS suffix: `home.example.com.`

Favorite suffixes:

- `someuniversity.example.com.`
- `farm1.friends.example.com.`

I have DHCP router configured at home and at the workplace. When I'm at the workplace and I say `ping host1`, then I want it to look for `host1.office.example.com.`, then `host1.someuniversity.example.com.` and finally `host1.farm1.friends.example.com.`.

When I'm home I want it to look for `host1.home.example.com`, then `host1.someuniversity.example.com.` and then `host1.farm1.friends.example.com.`.

As I see in the *Advanced TCP/IP settings*'s *DNS* tab the "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes" is mutually exclusive with "Append these DNS suffixes (in order):". Can I configure my goal here somehow? Or is there any sequence of commands I could use? Or something else?